# MySQL Error 2003 (HY000): Can connect from 127.0.0.1, but NOT via 192.168.1.53

Tags: mysql

hoping for a bit of help.  I just installed MySQL on Ubuntu and am running into issues connecting to it.

I am able to connect to the MySQL Server when running:
`mysql -u devuser -p -h 127.0.0.1 --port=3306`

But not when using the same machine's network address:
`mysql -u devuser -p -h 192.168.1.53 --port=3306`

---

devuser is setup as devuser@% in mysql

---

MySQL server is running

```
pp$> netstat -lnp | grep mysql
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3098/mysqld
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     50806    3098/mysqld          /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

---

connections to port 3306 are allowed from anywhere (configured in ufw)

```
pp$> ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
3306                       ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
3306/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
3306 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
3306/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

---

Thanks in advance.

PP

Answer (score 1):

Edit the MySQL config file at /etc/mysql/my.cnf and change the below line

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

to

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

That will allow the MySQL server to bind to any IP address.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that earlier, but then couldn't restart mysql:

pp$> systemctl restart mysql
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

pp$> systemctl status mysql.service
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-03-11 06:21:32 EDT
Process: 7810 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Comment: Run `journalctl -xe` and see what errors are shown in there.

Comment: Thanks, but nothing really in there -
mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
--
-- The result is RESULT.